# Timeout_value error in process when using timer:sleep(rand:uniform()*1000)

Tags: random, erlang

Trying to use `timer:sleep(rand:uniform()*1000)` in Erlang to create a random sleep period, but receive the following error:

```
Error in process <0.45.0> with exit value:
{timeout_value,[{timer,sleep,1,[{file,"timer.erl"}}]
```

Why might I be receiving this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rand:uniform()*1000` is a floating point value while `timer:sleep/1` only accepts integers. You can use `trunc` to convert the float to integer (discarding the value after the `.`):

```
timer:sleep(trunc(rand:uniform()*1000)).
```

or, even better, use `rand:uniform/1` to generate a random integer between 1 and N directly:

```
timer:sleep(rand:uniform(1000)).
```